# Interactive python console with autocomplete in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have an interactive REPL Python terminal in VS code with auto-complete capabilities?

I know you can:

1. Get a REPL window with 'Python: Start REPL', but that doesn't have auto-complete
2. Debug a Python project and when the debugger is paused use the 'Debug Console' as a REPL console with auto-complete capabilities.

It seems that the capability is there but I would like the auto-complete capabilities of the Debug console without having to run the debugger.

Is this possible?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3363#issuecomment-439277599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `IPython` for such a REPL. Otherwise please keep an eye on our data science support as that *just* launched and we plan to continue to improve it.

Comment: `ipython` is "ok" but obviously much inferior to the Debug console capabilities (rich output formats with folding. faster and more convenient code completion etc.) Looking forward to future developments of the extension